# Color unbounded cells of voronoi diagram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, voronoi

I have two sets of points and `plot` them in blue stars and red dots. Then I `plot` Voronoi diagram of both sets with `voronoi(X,Y)` function. I want to specify color of each cell depends on which set it's site is belong. I've almost done this one by the use of `patch` function this way:

```
     [v,c]=voronoin(D);
     for p=1:TheNumberOfSets
       r=rand()/2+0.5;    % random gray color
       col=[r r r];
       for s=1:PointsInSet(p)
           l=l+1;
           patch(v(c{l},1),v(c{l},2),col);  % color
           axis([0 10 0 10]);
       end
     end
```

Where`D` is the coordinates of the points of sets, `TheNumberOfSets` show how many sets do we have (in this particular part we have just 2 sets), `col` specify a random gray color, `PointsInSet` specify how many points do we have in each set and `l` is used to enumerate cells of Voronoi diagram.

and this is the result:
[image]

now my problem (as you can see!) is about unbounded cells. This code just change the color of the bounded cells and I want to color unbounded cells with their specified set's color in the range of axis box (i.e. the box that you can see in the image).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please add sample information of `TheNumberOfSets`, `PointsInSet`, `l`, `v`, `c`, `col`, and anything I may have missed? See the help file on [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information of how to make a proper example of your problem.

Comment: I've added some more information. @FranzHahn

Comment: What about `l`?

Comment: As you can read it in the question, I said "...and 'l' is used to enumerate cells of Voronoi diagram." and I use it to color cells one by one. Do you have any suggested code or algorithm to tell me about?! @FranzHahn

Comment: I would really like to help you, but I just don't know how your variables actually look. Can you just add initializations for each variable? The [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide suggests your post to contain information so that you "[m]ake sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included". With the initializations I can look into it.

Comment: The choice of `l` and `col` is irrelevant to the problem, so although a better MCVE would take a more straightforward approach to defining these, which would be welcome, my answer ignores this aspect of the example and works so long as `l` is a valid index of `c` and `col` is a valid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does in fact create `patch` objects for the unbounded cells, but because they contain vertices that have `Inf` values representing the unbounded edges, they aren't displayed. You need to replace these vertices with finite ones to complete the patches.

The vertices generated by `voronoi` to draw the unbounded cell edges are useful for this purpose. You can obtain these when drawing the voronoi diagram:

```
h = voronoi(D);
v1 = shiftdim(reshape([h(2).XData;h(2).YData],2,3,[]),2); % Arranged one edge per row, one vertex per slice in the third dimension
```

The unbounded edges are plotted last, so you can isolate these by counting unbounded cells in `c`:

```
nUnbounded = sum(cellfun(@(ic)ismember(1,ic),c));
v1Unbounded = v1(end-(nUnbounded-1):end,:,:);
```

The first listed vertex of these edges is the finite vertex of the cell. These don't always exactly match the coordinates returned by `voronoin` due to floating-point error, so identify which numbered vertices these correspond to by finding the minimum pairwise distance from `pdist2`:

```
[~,iBounded] = min(pdist2(v,v1Unbounded(:,:,1))); % Index of the bounded vertex
vUnbounded = v1Unbounded(:,:,2); % Displayed coordinate of the unbounded end of the cell edge
```

To substitute in these coordinates you can then replace `patch(v(c{l},1),v(c{l},2),col);` with the following:

```
cPatch = c{l}; % List of vertex indices
vPatch = v(cPatch,:); % Vertex coordinates which may contain Inf
idx = find(cPatch==1); % Check if cell has unbounded edges
if idx
    cPatch = circshift(cPatch,-idx); % Move the 1 to the end of the list of vertex indices
    vPatch = [vPatch(1:idx-1,:)
              vUnbounded(iBounded == cPatch(end-1),:)
              vUnbounded(iBounded == cPatch(1),:)
              vPatch(idx+1:end,:)]; % Replace Inf values at idx with coordinates from the unbounded edges that meet the two adjacent finite vertices
end
patch(vPatch(:,1),vPatch(:,2),col);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer (after a month, you're the first one). I just have one problem to run your code. After `h = voronoi(D);`, `h` has just one column not two chart line, so I receive error:**Improper index matrix reference** for `h(2).XData`. Of course I use MATLAB R2014a and saw **Note:The behavior of h = voronoi(..) has changed. The new behavior returns a vector of two chart line handles; one representing the points and the other representing the Voronoi edges** in [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html). Do u have any idea @Will ? Thanks again

Comment: Oh dear! It looks like in R2014a the line coordinates are still accessible via handles that are still returned in `h`, but the order of the handles and structure of the line data may not be as described above and you cannot use the dot notation as in `.XData` to access it. It isn't explicitly documented at all so will require a little exploration to determine where to find the correct values to substitute into the `patch` input as above. If I recall correctly you should be able to access all the line data using `get(h,{'XData','YData'})`.

Comment: Thank you again @Will . I've tried  `get(h,{'XData','YData'})` and received a `14x2` cell class for 7 points; Which is like this:

   first line: `[1x7 double]    [1x7 double]`

    second line:`[1x2 double]    [1x2 double]`

    third line: `[1x2 double]    [1x2 double]`
    ...
I'll try to figure it out and fit this for my code and I know that your answer is true. regards.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that in Matlab R2018a or later(R2014b is ok but I didn't test the R2015 ~ R2016), the voronoi doesn't return the same h as expected before, though the document of this function doesn't change.
In R2018a it returns

```matlab
 h(1)

ans = 

 handle to deleted Data
```

while in R2014b it returns

```matlab
h(1)

ans = 

  Line with properties:

              Color: [0 0.4470 0.7410]
          LineStyle: 'none'
          LineWidth: 0.5000
             Marker: '.'
         MarkerSize: 6
    MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
              XData: [1x200 double]
              YData: [1x200 double]
              ZData: [1x0 double]

  Show all properties
```

I was just wondering if there are some methods to extract the lines and vertices of unbounded cells in new version.